# Is there a way to monitor use of each client id that is making calls to App Engine Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an Google App Engine application that is no more than an endpoints app.

It stores master data and provides rest API to access.
There are many other applications that are not mine are using these endpoints calls.

Is there a way to monitor uses for each client id?

Say I want to know that how many calls one client id is making per week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not built in stats for client usage, but it shouldn't be to hard to implement a basic counter every time a user consumes one of your API. Are you planning to use this for billing? if not just make sure to buffer that counter using the memcache to reduce costs.

Comment: Well I am considering this because I am responsible for the endpoints app but not for other app that consumes the endpoints API. So I don't know if any of them might "overuse" or something. I want to have some knowledge that say if there is an app from another team suddenly increases the usage of the endpoints so that I could talk to them about this.   I have thought about implementing my own counter before every API call, but isn't that increasing work for each endpoints call? Making each call longer to respond.

Comment: you can just handle that counter on a task queue, that way it wont have any impact on the actual request.

Comment: Yep.  That's a good call. Just kick off a task. I think so far this could be the solution. Hope App Engine Team in Google could come up better ways to deal this.

Comment: I found something else as a workaround for this. I export the logs to a Cloud Storage Bucket and then have a standalone python script downloads logs everyday and analyze calls by user-agent (which contains app-id ).

Comment: As long as you don't go over the logging quota that should be OK.

Comment: Yep. That's a good call. Because currently my project is created using a prime account so quota is not a pressure. But I have some other free projects created not by prime account and does see sometimes the log hit the quota.

Answer (score 0):

No. It does not provide any separate logs. All logs can be seen at one place including app engine, cloud endpoints etc.